# Tone is not playing on Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino

I am trying to make a bot that follows a line with IR sensors and I also have a IR sensor to prevent collisions. In the if statement that stops movement, I also have it play a tone, but the problem is the tone doesn't play. I know that the if statement is being executed as the servos do stop as intended and resume after the object is removed. Also the speaker setup is confirmed working as other code with tones are working fine. I did hear it beep a few times when I was troubleshooting which is strange.

Here is the statement with the issue;

```
    if (irDetect == 0)   // Object detected
    {
      servoLeft.writeMicroseconds(1500);  // Stop left servo
      servoRight.writeMicroseconds(1500);  // Stop right servo
      tone(5, 4000, 100);
      delay(100);
    }
```

I cannot figure out the problem so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Tone and the ir library you are using are both using timer2.  So you have a timer conflict.  Both can't simultaneously have control over timer2.  You'll either need to find a new library for one function or the other or modify one to use a different timer.